# Accessing last element of map using map.end()

Tags: c++, stl

```
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    map <int, int > m;
    map <int, int>::iterator it1, it2;
    m[1] = 1;
    m[2] = 1;
    m[3] = 1;
    it1 = m.end()--;
    it2 = --m.end();

    cout << it1->first << " " << it1->second << endl;
    cout << it2->first << " " << it2->second << endl;
}
```

Output:

```
3 -1778731776 
3 1
```

The iterators are pointing to the same key but are giving different values. Why? I am unable to understand this odd behaviour. How does the post-decrement and the pre-decrement work here?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> The iterators are pointing to the same key

No they do not. `m.end()--;` is post decrement. Its semantic is to decrement the return value of `m.end()` as a side-effect, but return the **original value unchanged**. So `it1 == m.end()` and you get undefined behavior by dereferencing it.

It compiles successfully due to an unfortunate side-effect of `operator++` being a member function of a user defined type (the iterator). You can call it even on an r-value like `m.end()`, while the built-in post-decrement expects an l-value.

So even though iterators *model pointers*, they aren't quite the same. To contrast, this program:

```
char* foo();

int main() {
  foo()--;
}
```

[will produce an error on `foo()--`](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e926e54b4586a0a8), because `foo()` is an r-value pointer, and we cannot decrement it.

Comment: T'would be nice to have ref-qualified operators for iterators to avoid this case, but I guess some code depends on it.

Comment: @Quentin - Agreed. While I don't deny that applying overloaded operators to *some* r-values is damn useful (proxies ftw), it'd be nice if types that mimic built-ins mimicked them more fully.

Comment: The standard says that value categories names don't have a hyphen, you may refer to ISO14882:N4713. Maybe there's hyphens in other languages', but in the C++ term, there isn't.

Comment: @Constructor - And quite a few books *do* hyphenate them. Which I personally find clearer.

Comment: @StoryTeller It makes sense. I just mention it here, it may not be a big problem. :)